# When does muscle collapse on its own mass?

Tags: muscle

When talking about muscle to structural level but not cellular level

Bicep brachhii vs single muscle cell

How big can a muscle get before it collapses on its own mass or becomes unable to flex because of lack of space?

I remember once a study of bird muscles growing up to 300%  of their initial size but I can't find bigger numbers around the internet or if that specific number could grow with time or if it was the limit.

Comment: Ever seen an elephant? This may be better suited for a biology forum since this has nothing to do with fitness or even humans

Comment: I agree with @Raditz_35. This might be an interesting question for an evolutionary biology forum, but it is not applicable (in its current form) to this forum.